# why setName in Thread class assigns to a character array?why not a String?

Tags: java

When i was dealing with threads concept in Java, i have seen Thread.java source file. I noticed when `setName()` method assigns string to a character array called `"name[]"`. Java has a feature of String data type, then why they are using character array.

In source file it is initialised like,

```
private char name[]; // why not "private String name;"
```

In `setName()` method,

```
public final void setName(String name) {
    checkAccess();
    this.name = name.toCharArray();
    }
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This name is accessed from native code, so it is easier to handle char arrays than mangle with Java types. The `core-lib-devs` mailing list discussed this question a while ago, here's a [link](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2010-August/004686.html) to one mail from the thread. The original question stated that *"a fair amount of time goes to that Thread.setName call which I believe a significant portion is to do new char allocation and copy char array etc"*. Quoting bits of the answer:

> There was an RFE for this way back in late 2002:
>
> 4745629 (thread) Thread.setName does needless string allocations
>   (don't  use char[])
>
> The initial eval in 2002 stated:
>
> "I can't imagine that this seriously impacts the performance of any
>   real  program.  Furthermore, changing the fields in Thread is
>   problematic due  to the close relationship of this class with the VM. 
>   That said, it  might be worth addressing this in the context of some
>   Thread code-cleanup."
>
> Then in 2005 it was closed as "will not fix":
>
> "There are dependencies on the name representation being a char array
>   in  the JVM and this RFE must be respectfully rejected."

Comment: Can you back that up with some reference or something? I don't see anything in `Thread.java` or `Thread.c` (in the `native` tree) that makes the name accessible to native code. If it were accessed from native code, I'd expect to see a null character at the end. This seems like speculation.

Comment: That was great response , thank you. can i consider, it is one of the reason, java is not pure object oriented language ?

Comment: @kik: the **entire** "is Java a pure OO language" question is **useless** because no one who ever asked it was able to provide a useful definition of what exactly makes a "pure OO language". I'd love to be proven wrong, but so far it hasn't happened.

Comment: If you look around online, you'll see this question was raised about 10 years ago, there apparently was a RFE (4745629) to address this...the idea at the time was, in order to store it as a string, they would then have to sync up JVM changes with API changes, and I guess it was deemed too much since Thread is a prevalent object

Comment: @curtisk: If you can find that reference, you should post an answer with a link and a quote. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Unfortunately, the entire Oracle's (formerly Sun's) bug database is down at the moment, reporting internal errors... I found an email discussing the said RFE. Will update the answer.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov: *"Why the downvote?"* I downvoted the original, speculative answer. Speculation is not useful. I still think you open with speculation (there's a link between `Thread` and the JVM code, but we don't know that `name` is accessed from native code), but at least there's some value to the answer now.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder : alas, that one only appears as old email/thread talking about it, already tried looking in oracle's site to further substantiate it but no luck(as others have mentioned) interesting question nonetheless :p

Answer (score 4):

I think that this is most likely a historical artifact; i.e. something that was done a long time ago for reasons that are no longer relevant.

As Curtisk's comment indicates, it has been suggested that this be fixed.  But it sounds like the ideas has been set on one side because the effort to make the fix exceeds the benefit.  And it is pretty clear that the benefit of fixing this anomoly is miniscule ... unless you are creating lots of threads that do little real work.

The RFE (4745629) is no longer visible to Google, but [this mailing list posting](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2010-August/004686.html) by David Holmes @ Oracle refers to it:

> Xiaobin Lu said the following on 08/11/10 08:07:
>
> > Thanks for your reply. For a lot of enterprise applications (such as the 
> >     one I work for), a fair amount of time goes to that Thread.setName call 
> >     which I believe a significant portion is to do new char allocation and 
> >     copy char array etc. So I think we should give a second thought about 
> >     how we can efficiently store that field.
>
> There was an RFE for this way back in late 2002:
>
> 4745629 (thread) Thread.setName does needless string allocations (don't 
>   use char[])
>
> The initial eval in 2002 stated:
>
> "I can't imagine that this seriously impacts the performance of any real 
>   program.  Furthermore, changing the fields in Thread is problematic due 
>   to the close relationship of this class with the VM.  That said, it 
>   might be worth addressing this in the context of some Thread code-cleanup."
>
> Then in 2005 it was closed as "will not fix":
>
> "There are dependencies on the name representation being a char array in 
>   the JVM and this RFE must be respectfully rejected."
>
> ---
>
> Changing both the VM and the Java code is, as you know, a real pain to 
>   coordinate, so there would have to be some compelling performance 
>   evidence to support this (assuming it can be changed). Personally I 
>   agree with the initial eval above - if setName is impacting your overall 
>   performance then your threads can not be doing too much real work and 
>   you would seem to be creating far too many threads - so I'd be 
>   interested to here more about the context in which this occurs.