# Are all Thread methods (like getName/setName) thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

Is it safe to use `Thread`'s methods like `setName` / `getName` and some others from different threads? API does not say anything, but judging by the source code

```
private char name[];

public final void setName(String name) {
    checkAccess();
    this.name = name.toCharArray();
}

public final String getName() {
    return String.valueOf(name);
}
```

it seems that it may cause memory consistency errors.

Comment: Well, if the API says nothing, then it's safe to assume they're not thread-safe. That said, is it even possible for a thread to be interrupted in the middle of a simple field read / write? I'm not sure what sort of inconsistency would occur here, since the array is never modified in-place.

Comment: Those may not be the actual code, it could be that the methods are actually native and implemented with intrinsics.

Comment: It has to be synchronized to be thead-safe. Do you know what does `checkAccess()` method do?

Comment: @BheshGurung That doesn't make sense. `synchronized` and "thread-safe" are two different concepts and neither implies the other. And whatever `checkAccess()` does it can't really guarantee "thread-safety" (whatever that means) of code outside of the method call.

Comment: Some day your code could execute using a Java standard library implementation other than OpenJDK's. Or time could pass between when `getName` (ultimately `System.arrayCopy`) copies the contents of `name` and when `getName` returns a value. During that time, `setName` could change the value of `name`, thus causing `getName` to return a value that is no longer accurate, that is, consistent.

Comment: Scratching my head why the name is stored as char[] ? Cant think of a good reason except to save a few bytes storage... or maybe it better interfaces with native code parts.

Comment: Should be the other way round. APIs on a multithreaded, premeptive system should be threadsafe unless otherwise indicated.

Comment: @Gyro Gearless http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412408/why-setname-in-thread-class-assigns-to-a-character-arraywhy-not-a-string

Comment: Umm, I'm away from compiler now... can you actually change thread name once it's started?

Comment: @minopret It's pretty impossible for `Thread` to make consecutive calls to its methods Do The Right Thing w/r/t desired (i.e. "thread-safe" behaviour). It doesn't really make sense to consider that scenario when talking about the class, that's up to the client to handle. Saying that a given isolated method is "thread-safe" makes very little sense to begin with, but usually can be understood as "won't crash miserably" or "will return a consistent snapshot of internal state" or some such.

Comment: @DenisTulskiy Seeing as the cited code doesn't ever prevent that, and the documentation says no such thing, it's reasonable to assume that you can.

Comment: @Denis Tulskiy it's allowed. Actually name was not a good example, set/get priority makes more sense, but it has the same memory consistency issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Thread.getName()` is a property than can be queried by anyone at any time. For example, a monitor utility constantly queries names of all threads. So the method has to be thread safe, otherwise, there's no clear protocol about who can safely access it and when.

Though it's always been puzzling why `Thread` uses a `char[]` to save its name, you are raising a more important question, `getName()` is obviously not correctly synchronized. If one thread does `setName("abcd")`, another thread may observe `getName()->"ab\0\0"`.

I'll post the question to concurrency-interest list. see http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2013-March/010935.html

Comment: How so?  Either the input to `String.valueOf()` is the original `char[]` array, or the new one, but neither actual array is edited.

Comment: `name` could be assigned and visible to other threads, before its content is populated

Comment: @zhong.j.yu Will `name` really ever be assigned *before* `toCharArray()` executes? (I suppose JIT could reorder the operations in that way but it seems odd.)

Comment: @millimoose Yes according to java memory model. If we write that kind of code, it's a bug. But this is JDK code of a particular VM, it can assume particular execution characteristics that we cannot.

Comment: @zhong.j.yu I see what you mean now.  So using String here would fix the problem, because then setName would simply reset Thread.name to the an already initialized object, correct?

Comment: No. It is not thread safe. If the thread object is shared, race conditions can occur.

Comment: @sharakan String would be fine here since it's immutable (the fields are final). `char[N]` is more like a mutable class with N non-final `char` fields as far as Java Memory Model is concerned.

Comment: @xagyg thread-safe is not a clearly defined term, usually it's up to app to define. data race does not necessarily mean thread-unsafe.

Comment: @zhong.j.yu Given the small amount of information we have got, we should err on the safe side, that is, the assumption that multiple threads access the instance of the object. So, let me add some refinement, in the context of multi-threaded access, NO it is not safe.

Answer (score 3):

> "API does not say anything"

If an API does not say anything, than you never can asume that a method /class is thread safe.
As you can see from the source code, the acess to `name` is not mutual exclusive.
But for me it seems, that `name` has either the old value or the new one, nothing in between, so it looks safe for must uses of `get/setName().`

Comment: It's only thread-safe if the method call is only being made by a single thread. In the context of multi-threaded access (i.e. multiple threads calling get/satName()), it is not safe at all.

Comment: @xagyg why do you think that? what do you think that would happen in the worst case? my opinion: one thred sees the old name, the other the new name, although this is theoretical, because threas names usully are asigned once.

Comment: Assignment of the name is not atomic, where is mutual exclusivity guaranteed? It isn't. And "although this is theoretical, because threas names usully are asigned once" - the OP is not asking the *usual* case, he/she is asking if it is safe (i.e. in all use-cases, ALWAYS). No it isn't safe.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, if one thread invokes `setName` while access to `name` isn't somehow synchronized, there's no guarantee that any other thread will **ever** see that new value.

Second, `String.valueOf(char[])` iterates over `name`. That means if even *one* of `name`'s characters is set during this iteration, the iterating thread might see inconsistent data - the first characters of the original char array and the last characters of the other.

In this particular case, it's not one of characters, rather it's the pointer to the beginning of the char array. Assuming that an iteration over an array computes the next cell to access by adding the current iteration index to that pointer's referred address, it will indeed also cause inconsistent data.

** **EDIT** **

Regarding the second non-safe scenario, after reading [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210369/openjdk-implementation-of-system-arraycopy), it seems much less obvious as to how actually an array copy is implemented - it is platform-dependent. This explains why `String,valueOf(char[])` isn't documented as thread-safe. So, anyway, the second scenario still applies as non-thread-safe.

Comment: I just saw "it isn't thread-safe" so upvoted you. You are correct. :). You were the first person to say that.

Answer (score 0):

**If the thread object is shared** amongst other threads (which might be unusual, but nevertheless possible - if you programmed a solution that way), then it is NOT thread-safe. It is susceptible to race conditions, just like any other class or object.

Example:

```
Thread t1 = new SomeThread(); t1.start();
(new MyThread(t1, new Runnable() { public void run() {t1.setName("HELLO");} })).start();
(new MyThread(t1, new Runnable() { public void run() {t1.setName("GOODBYE");} })).start();
```

Two threads accessing same thread object t1. **Not safe.**